# Converting a column of floats into cumulative percentages

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tiF6.jpg)

Hey I have a column of floats in 'close' need to convert into cumulative percentages and store it in 'cum_p'.

I got this script to help me but I messed a step or two up:

```
import os
import sys
import csv


def adjust_cryptors_file(source, /, values, close):
    with open(source) as f:
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)][1:]

    agg_data = []

    ix = 0
    total = 0
    while ix < len(data):
        # value to add to the running total
        row = data[ix]

        # Column 20 / Index 19
        v = float(row[values])

        total += v

        # percentage of running total
        p = (total / 3797.14) * 100

        closed = row[close]

        # add to new list of data
        agg_data.append([v, p, closed])

        # increment index counter
        ix += 1

    agg_data.insert(0, ['timestamp', 'close', 'cum_p'])

    parent = os.path.dirname(source)
    dest = os.path.join(parent, 'modified.data')

    with open('modified.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(agg_data)

    print(f"Your new modified data file: {dest}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Enter your CSV file here
    source = 'BTCUSDT-1d-data.csv'
    column_of_timestamp = 1
    column_of_close = 5

    adjust_cryptors_file(source, values=column_of_timestamp, close=column_of_close)
```

I would really appreciate some help or a pointer :)
The first value would be 0% the 2nd value would be the % difference from the first and 2nd value in 'close'.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the .csv file you are using? I would like to help buy want to make sure the format is conforming to the one you are using, so that I don't get a potentially incompatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving each row in the `agg_data` List, then we can use that list to access the previous row's data for `close`. I have added it in as a conditional judging by what you indicated you wanted:

```
# percentage of running total
        p = (total / 3797.14) * 100

        # new conditional statement to deal with the 'cum_p' column
        if ix == 0:
            closed = 0
        else:
            closed = ((p - agg_data[ix-1][1])/agg_data[ix-1][1]) * 100

        # add to new list of data
        agg_data.append([v, p, closed])
```

Here is the sample output I am getting now for the `cum_p` column in `modified.csv`.

[image: Sample Output]

**Edit**: I was using the values in `close` from the `modified.csv` file. Let me know if you meant `close` from the original `BTCUSDT-1d-data.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
df["cum_p"] = pd.Series.cumsum(df.close)/df.close.sum()*100
```

It gives the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using

```
import pandas as pd
```

if **name** == '**main**':
source = 'BTCUSDT-1d-data.csv'

```
# create dataframe from csv file
df = pd.read_csv(source)

# calculate the cum_pnl
daily_close = df['close']
daily_returns = pd.Series(daily_close).pct_change(1)
cum_pnl = daily_returns.cumsum()

# add cum_pnl column
df['cum_pnl'] = cum_pnl

# filter to only columns that we want:
df = df[['timestamp', 'close', 'cum_pnl']]

# export it as csv again
df.to_csv('btcdailychange.csv')
```

That gave me individual % change for every row
Then I simply made a new column['sum'] and:

```
df['sum'] = df["cum_pnl"].cumsum()
```

Thanks for all the replies!